# Conditional and Joint Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Box 1 : 5 white and 2 black balls
Box 2 : 2 white and 1 black balls
Box 3 : 2 white and 3 black balls

One box is selected at random and one ball is drawn from it. What is the probability that it will be white?

I think the answer is 1/3(5/7 + 2/3 + 2/5) = 187/315.

Is this correct?

Also calculate the probability the first box was selected given that a white ball was drawn? I am stumped on this second questions. I think it is P(1 | W) which comes out to more than 1 which is obviously not right.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How do you get $P(1\mid W)$ to be more than one?  What are you doing?

Comment: I had P(1|W) = P(1 intersection W) / P(W) which is correct. However, I did not make the connection that the answer to my first question (which is correct) is indeed P(W).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\sf P}}$You've got the first part right.  I'm not sure what you're doing on the second.  You need to apply Bayes' Rule.

Let $W$ be the event of choosing a white ball, and $B$ be the number of the box chosen.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Then by} & \text{ the law of total probability:}
\\[1ex]\P(W) & = \P(B=1)\P(W\mid B=1)+\P(B=2)\P(W\mid B=2)+\P(B=3)\P(W\mid B=3)
\\[1ex] & = \frac 1 3\Bigl(\P(W\mid B=1)+\P(W\mid B=2)+\P(W\mid B=3)\Bigr)
\\[1ex] & = \frac 1 3\Bigl(\frac 5 7+\frac 2 3+ \frac 2 5\Bigr)
\\[4ex] \text{Then apply} & \text{ Bayes' Rule:}
\\[1ex]
\P(B=1\mid W) & = \frac{P(B=1)P(W\mid B=1)}{P(W)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\frac 1 3\cdot\frac 5 7}{\frac 1 3\Bigl(\frac 5 7+\frac 2 3+ \frac 2 5\Bigr)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{75}{75 + 70 + 42}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you please help with my other question?

Comment: What other question? @user100503

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937324/cryptography-probability

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question is indeed $P(1|W)=75/187$ which is less then $1$. 
 Using Bayes theorem, 
$P(1|W)=\frac{P(W|1).P(1)}{P(W|1).P(1)+P(W|2).P(2)+P(W|3).P(3)}$

$P(1|W)=\frac{(5/7).(1/3)}{(5/7).(1/3)+(2/3).(1/3)+(2/5).(1/3)}$

$P(1|W)=75/187$ 
Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please help with my other question?

Comment: I am sorry, I log off right after my last comment and just log in. I just read your comment, and I see that your recent questions have answers already.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937324/cryptography-probability